# Getting value of other attributes on datalist select

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-datalist

I have a datalist:

```
<datalist id="subjects">
<?php foreach($subjects as $v){ ?>
        <option data-subjectid="<?php echo $v[2]; ?>" value="<?php echo ucwords($v[1]); ?>"><?php echo ucwords($v[1]); ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

What I want to do is to get the value stored in the `data-subjectid` attribute of the value that is selected. What I have been doing up until now is to call the `.each()` function in jQuery like this:

```
//on Select Change
var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
$('#subjects option').each(function(){
   if(current_value == selectedvalue){
      //get the data-subjectid of current value   
   }
});
```

Is there a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried $(this).attr('data-subjectid')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is faster (I'm not 100% sure how this selector works under the covers) but you can use the [:selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to make the code a little cleaner.

```
var subjectId = $('#subjects option:selected').attr('data-subjectid');
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the `datalist` options don't support the `:selected` pseudo-class (because one `datalist` can provide for multiple form fields, so technically multiple options can be selected at once by different inputs)